# Bootstrap 3.3.7 XSS

Tags: xss

I found that **Bootstrap 3.3.7** is vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) via the data-target, data-template, data-content, data-title and data-viewport attributes. How can I inject the XSS into these particular attributes?

Comment: I thought you had found out that it was vulnerable. Why are you asking now if it is vulnerable?

Comment: @MechMK1, I have found a vulnerability report on snyk.io.

Comment: So an automated tool told you that bootstrap 3.3.7 was vulnerable to something, and now you want to ask how you can exploit this vulnerability?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You are asking for exploit to a known/unknown vulnerability. You should first search Github, blog posts all around the web, and if nothing, you should not ask other people, because people prefer to keep exploits private. XSS has a very good coverage in blog posts from some people.

Comment: @MechMK1, mate I am currently learning how to do these things. I don't really understand why there should always be a person like you trying to stop me from learning? You could just give me a hint of what to search further.

Comment: @Kite I'm not trying to "turn you down", I'm trying to find out what you want to know. Learning how to identify and exploit XSS vulnerabilities is completely fine. In fact, feel free to stop by [the DMZ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) once you have enough rep. The fact of the matter is though that questions, seeking to exploit a particular vulnerability without in-depth understanding of the underlying mechanics, are off-topic.

Comment: @Kite If you are interested in learning more on this subject, [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Cross_site_scripting) has an excellent guide on this. This website also contains references to further articles, which should aid your understanding of how XSS works.

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel like you're being shut out Kite.  No one is trying to stop you from learning.  Stackoverflow just isn't your usual forum, and as a result it's just not a great fit for these kinds of questions.  The goal here is to create a repository of questions and answers.  It's not intended for the usual back-and-forth that you might get in a more typical forum.  As a result, very broad questions are very difficult to answer well.  Unfortunately, "X is vulnerable, what do I do?" is about as broad as questions get.  If you can edit to include more details, you can get a good answer.

Comment: @ConorManconem, what details should I include?

Comment: @Kite At least you should add (a reference to) the original CVE details of the vulnerability so we can take a look into it.

Comment: @user319472, here you are - CVE-2016-10735.

Comment: Hello! I looked at the issues that @Shashbuckler listed. If I understood, I should try this `data-target="<img src=x onerror=alert(0)>`. I found the bootstrap file on the website, but how to change this attribute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you look at some of the issues as they were filed against Bootstrap.  Sample exploits are provided, examples:

- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20184
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27044
- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27045

Comment: Thank you! If I understood, I should try `data-target="<img src=x onerror=alert(0)>`. I found the bootstrap file on the website (Inspect -> Sources), but how to change this attribute value?

Comment: You can make it whatever you want.  The vulnerability, which is unlikely in most apps, is when any of the data used on the right hand side of '=' is specified by an attacker and is not filtered by the software.